# How to include other field in Mongodb aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of retweets which I would like to show who retweets the most.

This is the sample data.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55cf3400dd232e1b561b6b2c"),
    ....
    "user" : {
        "id" : 1.77202e+08,
        ...
        "screen_name" : "Karunaprof",

    },
    ...
}, 
{ ... }
```

So each document is a retweet. I can aggregate which user retweets the most but it only returns `_id` i would like the result to return `screen_name` as well.

Here's my query.

```
db.getCollection('raw_tweets').aggregate(
    { $group : { _id: "$user.id_str", count : { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $match : { count : { $gte : 1 } } },
    { $sort : { count : -1 } },
)
```

Here's my result

```
{
    "_id" : "121817564",
    "count" : 1419.0000000000000000
}
```

My expected result would be

```
{
    "_id" : "121817564",
    "count" : 1419.0000000000000000,
    "screen_name" : "screen_name"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `$group` stage, you can add another field `screenname` and set it using `$first` or `$last` to take it from the first or last document in that group:

```
db.getCollection('raw_tweets').aggregate(
    { $group : { _id: "$user.id", screenname: { $last :"$user.screen_name"}, count : { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $match : { count : { $gte : 1 } } },
    { $sort : { count : -1 } }
)
```

Without a sort specified, the order of the documents isn't defined so the document which will be selected as first/last is also undefined. If a user's screenname never changes, or if you don't care which screenname is picked up, the approach above should be sufficient.

If the screenname can change and you do care which screenname is picked up, you'll need to add some more logic. For example if you decided to take the most recent screenname, you could order by date ascending and then pick the last screenname:

```
db.getCollection('raw_tweets').aggregate(
    { $sort : { date : 1 } },
    { $group : { _id: "$user.id", screenname: { $last :"$user.screen_name"}, count : { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $match : { count : { $gte : 1 } } },
    { $sort : { count : -1 } }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

it would look like this:

```
db.getCollection('tweets').aggregate( [
        {
            $group : {
                _id: { id : "$user.id", screen_name: "$user.screen_name" },
                count : { $sum : 1 } 
            } 
        },
        { $match : { count : { $gte : 1 } } },
        { $sort : { count : -1 } },
        { $project : { "_id": "$_id.id", "screen_name": "$_id.screen_name", count :1 } }
    ]
)
```

and you'd get output in the shell like:

```
{
  "waitedMS": NumberLong("0"),
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": 177202000,
      "count": 1,
      "screen_name": "Karunaprof"
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```